# Passing values from two volley requests to Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, parameter-passing, android-volley

So i am making two volley requests on my MainActivity. Both return a JSONArray which then i parse into ArrayList.

My question is there a way to pass both of those arrayLists from the MainActivity to MainActivity2?

MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                SplashScreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                SplashScreen.this.finish();
            }
        }, 5000);
    }

    public void getAtm1(Context context){
        VolleyRequests.getJson(RequestURL.getAtmURL(),context, new VolleyJsonListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
               ArrayList<Atm> atmArrayList1 = XmlHandler.getAtmArrayList(response);
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(String error) {
                // error
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something went wrong. Please try again later",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("Error.Response","Error"+ error);
            }
        });
    }
    public void getAtm2(Context context){
        VolleyRequests.getJson(RequestURL.getAtmURL(),context, new VolleyJsonListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                ArrayList<Atm> atmArrayList2 = XmlHandler.getAtmArrayList(response);
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(String error) {
                // error
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something went wrong. Please try again later",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("Error.Response","Error"+ error);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know how to pass data between Activities in general?

Comment: Yes i do. I am able to pass the ArrayList from one of the requests. But i cant seem to get my code right to pass both ArrayList

Comment: just wait untill both of them are ready (when each request finishes - check if another one finished, and if yes - pass both lists)